# Vertical divider (border) of same length

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3

I have a simple bootstrap grid with `row` and `col-` classes. I want to achieve a table like appereance with vertical dividers which have the full length equal to the heighest column.

I prepared a demo which revealse that with classical approaches the divider is only as long as the current column is. http://www.bootply.com/8egTicqQAq

I looked up different other questions on SO with accepted solutions. But non of them was working for me. At least not in the newest version of Chrome. But every modern browser should be targeted with the requested solution.

Comment: Can you use flexbox?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add a `display: table` to `.row` and `display: table-cell` and `float: none` to `.col`:

```
.row {
    width: 100%;
    margin: 2px;
    border-top: black solid 1px;
    border-bottom: black solid 1px;
    border-left: black solid 1px;
    border-right: black solid 1px;
    display: table;
}

.row > div[class^=col-] {
    border-right: black solid 1px;
    float: none;
    display: table-cell;
}

.row > div[class^=col-]:last-child {
  border:none;
}
```

**Example:** http://www.bootply.com/DNBL5ir8dG

Comment: Instead of **`div[class^=col-]`**, you can use **`div[class|=col]`**.